# Hyperparameters tuning with Google Cloud ML Engine and XGBoost

Tags: scikit-learn, google-cloud-platform, xgboost, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to replicate the hyperparameter tuning example reported at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-hyperparameter-tuning) but I want to use scikit learn XGBoost instead of tensorflow in my training application.

I am able to run multiple trials in a single job, on for each of the hyperparameters combination. However, the Training output object returned by ML-Engine does not include the *finalMetric* field, reporting metric information (see the differences in the picture below).

What I get with the example of the link above:
[Training output object with Tensorflow training app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SO0F.png)

What I get running my Training application with XGBoost:
[Training output object with XGBoost training app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djTEx.png)

Is there a way for XGBoost to return training metrics to ML-Engine?

It seems that this process is automated for tensorflow, as specified in the documentation:

> How Cloud ML Engine gets your metric
>
> You may notice that there are no instructions in this documentation
>   for passing your hyperparameter metric to the Cloud ML Engine training
>   service. That's because the service monitors TensorFlow summary events
>   generated by your training application and retrieves the metric.

Is there a similar mechanism for XGBoost?

Now, I can always dump each metric results to a file at the end of each trial and then analyze them manually to select the best parameters. But, by doing so, am I loosing the automated mechanism offered by Cloud ML Engine, especially concerning the "ALGORITHM_UNSPECIFIED" hyperparameters search algorithm?

i.e.,

> ALGORITHM_UNSPECIFIED: [...] applies Bayesian optimization to search
>   the space of possible hyperparameter values, resulting in the most
>   effective technique for your set of hyperparameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperparameter tuning support of XGBoost was implemented in a different way. We created the [cloudml-hypertune python package](https://pypi.org/project/cloudml-hypertune/) to help do it. We're still working on the public doc for it. At the meantime, you can refer to this [staging sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/wenzhel-sklearn/xgboost/iris#tuning-hyperparameters-on-cloud-ml-engine) to learn about how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, the example was very useful. 
Just one small comment:
The value of the parameter "global_step" within the "report_hyperparameter_tuning_metric" function of the cloudml-hypertune package is reported in the training output object, inside the tag "trainingStep" of "finalMetric". As such, it would be more useful to pass the best_ntree_limit parameter of the model, in case early stopping is used (rather than assigning always a value of 1, as in the example).

Answer (score 0):

Sara Robinson over at google put together a good post on how to do this. Rather than regurgitate and claim it as my own, I'll post this here for anyone else that comes across this post:

https://sararobinson.dev/2019/09/12/hyperparameter-tuning-xgboost.html